# File I/O with std::basic_ifstream<std::byte>

Tags: c++, c++17

Is `std::basic_ifstream` supposed to work with `std::byte` as the `CharT`?

The following `snippet.cpp` [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7eK5TK):

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

auto main() -> int {
    std::basic_string<std::byte> data { std::byte{0x12}, std::byte{0x13} };
    std::basic_ofstream<std::byte>("path") << data;
    std::basic_stringstream<std::byte> ss {};
    ss << std::basic_ifstream<std::byte>("path").rdbuf();
    assert(data == ss.str());
}
```

fails the assertion. The file is created, but it's empty.

How am I supposed to read/write `std::basic_string<std::byte>` to the filesystem?

```
$ g++ --std=c++17 snippet.cpp && ./a.out
a.out: code.cpp:10: int main(): Assertion `data == ss.str()' failed.

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: on which compiler does the assertion fail?  cannot reproduce on msvc and gcc.

Comment: It's gcc 9.3, I've added some details.

Comment: The standard doesn't require the implementation to provide `std::char_traits<std::byte>`, so just using `std::basic_string<std::byte>` already relies on internal implementation details; if it compiles, it's only by accident. Besides, the program lacks `#include <string>`